# mjml command not found

Tags: node.js, npm, mjml

I'm trying to install MJML (https://mjml.io/) and have done this according to the documentation:

`sudo npm install mjml`

The output given is as follows:

```
localhost:~ andy$ sudo npm install mjml
Password:
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/andy/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/andy/package.json'
npm WARN andy No description
npm WARN andy No repository field.
npm WARN andy No README data
npm WARN andy No license field.

+ mjml@4.4.0-beta.1
updated 1 package and audited 27385 packages in 1.934s
```

I've created a `test.mjml` file but when I try and compile it with:

`mjml test.mjml -o output.html`

It gives:

```
-bash: mjml: command not found
```

I've Googled the issue and found:

- https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/885
- https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/634
- https://github.com/mjmlio/mjml/issues/799

But none of these seem to have helped or apply in my situation.

If anyone out there uses MJML please can you help with this?

I'm running it on a Mac under Mojave 10.14.2

If I try `which mjml` it gives nothing.

The executable seems to exist, in `/Users/andy/node_modules/mjml/bin`. If I actually `cd` into this directory and run `mjml --version` it gives:

```
mjml-core: 4.4.0-beta.1
mjml-cli: 4.4.0-beta.1
```

But then if I try `mjml ~/Desktop/mjml/test.mjml -o output.html` it says...

`-bash: mjml: command not found`

That doesn't make sense in my mind because it can execute `mjml` for `mjml --version` to work.

Comment: I have this problem now, exactly the same, I wonder still how to solve. Answers provided here are not ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can access mjml commands in the folder where you installed MJML with:

```
/Users/andy/node_modules/mjml/bin test.mjml -o output.html
```

To avoid typing ./node_modules/.bin/, add it to your PATH:

```
export PATH="$PATH:./node_modules/.bin"
```

After that you can run MJML directly, in that folder:

```
mjml test.mjml -o output.html
```

If you want to have the command executable from any folder, you can see how to do it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/how-can-i-make-a-program-executable-from-everywhere/3820#3820).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to resolve the issue. Make sure the mjml is installed globally

```
npm install -g mjml
```